# how to list subpages in sidebar without widget

Tags: pages, sidebar, children

I am trying to create a list of subpages of a parent page, which will appear in the sidebar of my wordpress site. This sidebar will appear on every page.

So for example, I have a page with an ID of 54. This page has 7 subpages. I would like to display these 7 pages in the sidebar (just the titles), as well as any more subpages that get added.

There is a currently a widget called 'Pages' that will do this, but I would like to do this via code directly in the sidebar.php rather than using a widget as there are a few constraints with using the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution would be:

```
<li><ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.''); ?>
</ul></li>
```

Use this code for more flexibility:

```
<?php if ( is_page() ) { ?>

<?php
if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0'); else
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
if ($children) { ?>

<li>
<h2>
<?php
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
echo $parent_title;
?>
</h2>
<ul>
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
</li>
<?php } } ?>
```